# What is the most gas efficient way to read and write to global contract state?

Tags: solidity, mapping, struct, state-variable, list

Say I have a complex(`list`, `mapping` or `struct`) global/contract variable. What is the most gas efficient way to update that variable in a function that changes the value of one or more ***indexes***, ***values*** or ***members*** in the case of the variable being a `list`, `mapping` or `struct` respectively.

The first option I can think of would be to directly write the value/s to state, but I think this would be the most gas intensive as for every direct update you have one read and one write operation.

The second option would be to read that variable into a local state variable, perform updates on that local variable, then assign the global variable to that local variable. This initially seems to be more gas efficient than option 1, but this would only be true if the gas cost of assignment is fixed, for example if the contract variable is a `list` then gas cost to write the local `list` to the contract `list` is fixed regardless of the length, so the gas cost of assigning a local `list` to a contract `list` of length 1 is equal to the gas cost if the `list` was of length 1000, and similarly for other complex types i.e. `mapping` and `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the following `list` example in Remix and it appears that option 2 is more gas expensive as it reassigns every element in the global list, not just the changed values. I'd assume the same issue would exist for `mapping` making option 2 the better option for `list` and `mapping`, but for `struct` variables(assuming the `struct` is composed of simple members i.e. no `mapping` or `list` members) option 2 would be more gas efficient as per [my previous test](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/118802/86303)

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract ComplexType {

    uint[100] public numbers;

    struct Number {
        uint number;
        uint index;
    }
    
    // option 1: direct update to indexes in state
    function push1(Number[] memory indexesToChange) external {

        for (uint i=0; i < indexesToChange.length; i++) {
            numbers[indexesToChange[i].index] += indexesToChange[i].number;
        }
    }

    // option 2: read state into local, update local then write local to state
    function push2(Number[] memory indexesToChange) external {

        uint[100] memory _numbers = numbers;

        for (uint i=0; i < indexesToChange.length; i++) {
            _numbers[indexesToChange[i].index] += indexesToChange[i].number;
        }

        numbers = _numbers;
    }    
}
```